# Using gems in Ruby *basic*

Tags: ruby, cmd, rubygems

I'm a complete newbie.

I have a gem I want to install and use, let's say it's this one:

https://rubygems.org/gems/linkedindata/versions/0.0.22

I'm using cmd:

```
gem install linkedindata
#1 gem installed
```

After that I add it to my gemfile:

```
gemrat 'linkedindata'
#gem 'linkedindata', '0.0.22' added to your Gemfile.
```

Now to use linkedindata I have to create a new object and specify my search. So I do:

```
**test.rb**
l = LinkedinData.new(1, "c:/users/proxylist.txt", true, true)
searchTerms = ['First', 'Second', 'Third']
l.getByKeywords(searchTerms)
```

Now I run the test.rb from command prompt:

```
test.rb:1:in `<main>': undefined local variable or meth
od `linkedindata' for main:Object (NameError)
```

So, I obviously need to require the 'linkedindata' gem here. I added:

```
**test.rb**
require 'LinkedinData'
l = LinkedinData.new(1, "c:/users/proxylist.txt", true, true)
searchTerms = ['First', 'Second', 'Third']
l.getByKeywords(searchTerms)
```

I get the following error:

```
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `re
quire': cannot load such file -- linkedin-scraper (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require
.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/linkedindata-0.0.22/lib/linkedin
data.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require
.rb:128:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require
.rb:128:in `rescue in require'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require
.rb:39:in `require'
        from C:/Users/test.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here? Or is there a problem with this gem?

***UPDATE***

The problem was within the gem, see Doon's answer below.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'linkedindata'
l = LinkedinData.new(1, "proxylist.txt", true, true)
searchTerms = ['First', 'Second', 'Third']
l.getByKeywords(searchTerms)
```

++++ correct how the gem requires "linkedin_scraper" in linkedindata.rb

Next problem occurs

```
 C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/linkedindata-0.0.22/lib/linkedin.rb:6:in `<cl
ass:Profile>': uninitialized constant Linkedin::Profile::ProxyManager (NameError
)
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/linkedindata-0.0.22/lib/linkedin
.rb:5:in `<module:Linkedin>'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/linkedindata-0.0.22/lib/linkedin
.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from linkedinscrape.rb:4:in `require'
        from linkedinscrape.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

Which obviously has to do with the proxy settings. The list:

```
**proxylist.txt**
220.248.224.242:8089
165.139.179.225:8080
54.207.114.172:3333
190.63.174.246:8081
```

The way I load it:

```
l = LinkedinData.new(1, "c:/users/proxylist.txt")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using a `Gemfile`, you are using bundler.  In your script you will need to include `rubygems` and `bundler` to make it work. Try this

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'

require 'linkedindata'

l = LinkedinData.new(1, "c:/users/proxylist.txt", true, true)
searchTerms = ['First', 'Second', 'Third']
l.getByKeywords(searchTerms)
```

You have run `bundle install`, sorry not familiar with gemrat, so not sure how much it does for you.

if you are not actually using `bundler`, just remove `require 'bundler/setup'` from the code above,  you will still need to require rubygems though in your script.

in looks like the gem itself is kind of broken in the way it declare dependencies,  and the other gems that it relies on.   I appear to be able to make it work as follows:

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'linkedin-scraper'
gem 'linkedindata'
gem 'generalscraper'
gem 'uploadconvert'
gem 'docsplit'
gem 'crack'
gem 'pry'
gem 'activesupport'
gem 'selenium-webdriver'
```

It also appears that it the `linkedin-scraper` needs to required as `linkedin_scraper` but not sure why that is.  So editing.

`{GEMPATH}/linkedindata-0.0.22/lib/linkedindata.rb` to `require 'linkedin_scraper'` as opposed to `require 'linkedin-scraper'`  seems to make it work.

So with the above changes and using bundler

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'linkedindata'
l = LinkedinData.new(1, "proxylist.txt", true, true)
searchTerms = ['First', 'Second', 'Third']
l.getByKeywords(searchTerms)
```

now runs (I don't have a proxylist.txt so it blows up looking for it, but it doesn't get anymore library errors).

Comment: Solved some errors, but i still get: `C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/linkedindata-0.0.22/lib/linkedindata.rb:1:in
`require': cannot load such file -- linkedin-scraper (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/linkedindata-0.0.22/lib/linkedin
data.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Users/test.rb:4:in `require'
        from C:/Users/test.rb:4:in `<main>'`

Comment: hmm it seems that the gem doesn't have its dependencies quite right.  you can try adding `gem 'linkedin-scraper'` but I too am having issues getting it to load, and not sure why...

Comment: ok it seems like the gem itself is a bit broken,  and doesn't declare all of it's dependencies correctly..  Will edit with what I've found...

Comment: Works like a charm -- as you said! It freezes with the proxy for me too though... C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/linkedindata-0.0.22/lib/linkedin.rb:6:in `<cl
ass:Profile>': uninitialized constant Linkedin::Profile::ProxyManager (NameError
)
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/linkedindata-0.0.22/lib/linkedin
.rb:5:in `<module:Linkedin>'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/linkedindata-0.0.22/lib/linkedin
.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from linkedinscrape.rb:4:in `require'
        from linkedinscrape.rb:4:in `<main>'. I don't understand this...